# Oracle update single table with multiple WHERE clauses

Tags: oracle

Just been doing some migration of data in our 11g and found a situation, where I would normally just create a few separate UPDATE scripts and got to thinking. Is there a way to do multiple updates with different WHERE clauses in the same script?

I mean instead of

```
UPDATE table1 SET value1=X WHERE value1=A;
UPDATE table1 SET value1=Y WHERE value1=B;
UPDATE table1 SET value1=Z WHERE value1=C;
```

Could you do something nearer

```
UPDATE table1 SET value1=X WHERE value1=A,SET value1=Y WHERE value1=B, SET value1=Z WHERE value1=Z;
```

Obviously the above syntax is wrong, but that's my point. Can something like this be done, or do you just have to do the three separate scripts?

Thanks in advance

KS

Comment: I'm not a big fan of UPDATING a column depending on it's own value.. especially multiple of these, combined. Updates with conditions on _other_ columns seem logically a bit safer.

Comment: I think your second SQL has a typo, at the end it says `WHERE value1=Z`, but in the first SQL it says `WHERE value1=C`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 SET value1 = CASE
           WHEN value1=A THEN X
           WHEN value1=B THEN Y ELSE XYZ
        END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `CASE` expression:

```
update table1
set value1 = case
        when value1 = A then X
        when value1 = B then Y
        when value1 = C then Z
    end
where
value1 in (A, B, C);
```

Answer (score 2):

OR DECODE().

```sql
update table1 set
value1 = decode(value1, A, X
                      , B, Y
                      , C, Z
                         , value1
               )
where value1 in (A, B, C);
```